# Aiming to create vs. aiming at creating

Tags: grammaticality

> The celebrities that organized the marathon were aiming **to create** an awareness about the treatment of diabetes.
>
> The celebrities that organized  the marathon were aiming **at creating** an awareness about the treatment of diabetes.

Are these two sentence grammatical correct, and if they are correct, what is the difference in there meaning

Answer (score 1):

'to create' is the infinitive form of the verb, and 'aiming to create' is certainly correct.

I would say 'aiming at creating' is also correct, but using 'to create' sounds more educated.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are understandable, meaning the celebrities are trying to increase awareness about diabetes.

> One aims **to** *do something*, and one aims **at** *an objective*

Your first sentence might be better as

> ...were **aiming to** ***create*** awareness...  *( where there was none before )*
>   ...were **aiming to** ***increase*** awareness...  *( to a greater level )*

Your second sentence is a bit verbose in construction, possibly better might be

> The celebrities that organized the marathon were **aiming at** increasing awareness about **diabetes treatment**.

Using

> creating **an** awareness

implies there are several different kinds or types of awareness, whereas with awareness there is usually differing levels of understanding.